# Calculate line coefficients for each row of a dataset with NA values in R

Tags: r, na, coefficients

I have a dataset with about 75 rows and 25 columns, each row shows one student and the columns show a score between 1 and 5.

```
            S1   S2      ..... S24
x1           0   2       ..... 2
x2           1   3       ..... Na
x3           NA  4       ..... 4
x4           4   NA      ..... 2
x5           4   3       ..... 2
```

I want to have the intercept and slope of each line without considering the NA values for each row and add them to the original dataset. I am using the code below, but it still includes NA values. I am using R.

```
df = read.csv('exc.csv')

Slope = function(x) {
  TempDF = data.frame(x, survey=1:ncol(df))
  lm(x ~ survey, data=TempDF,na.rm=TRUE)$coefficients[2]
}

Intercept = function(x) {
  TempDF = data.frame(x, survey=1:ncol(df))
  lm(x ~ survey, data=TempDF,na.rm=TRUE)$coefficients[1]
}

TData = as.data.frame(t(df))

dataset$Intercept = sapply(TData, Intercept)
dataset$slope = sapply(TData, Slope)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the regression by itself works only with pairs of non-NA values. So anything with NA values will not affect the slope or intercept in your case:

```
set.seed(100)
y = rnorm(100)
x = rnorm(100)
y[1:10] = NA
x[91:100] = NA
df = data.frame(x,y)
lm(y ~x,data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x
    0.02871     -0.15929
```

And we use only pairs in x and y with no NAs:

```
df = df[!is.na(df$x) & !is.na(df$y),]
lm(y ~x,data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x
    0.02871     -0.15929
```

If you also need it for something else, here's how you do it:

```
#simulate your data
df = data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,25*5,replace=TRUE),ncol=25))
colnames(df) = paste("S",1:25,sep="")
#make some NAs
df[cbind(c(1,3,5),c(2,3,4))] <- NA

# fit once, take both coefficient and intercept
Coef = function(x) {
  TempDF = data.frame(x, survey=1:ncol(df))
  TempDF = TempDF[!is.na(x),]
  c(lm(x ~ survey, data=TempDF)$coefficients,n=nrow(TempDF))
}

TData = as.data.frame(t(df))

dataset = data.frame(t(sapply(TData, Coef)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. the third piece of your code was what exactly I was looking for . is this still working correctly (I have more than 2 columns) when I have NA values? I don't want NA values to be considered as 0. or I should write in my code using !is.na(). sorry I am new to R . These are the score of the confidence for each column each week and then I wanna use intercept and slope for each row to run a multiple regression to see how it affected their final grades. is it ok to do so?

Comment: I have updated the answer above. Maybe easier to use !is.na(x) . I also included a column to show how many observations are used. As for your question on multiple regression.. it's not so easy for me to answer without getting a context on what you are trying to do